# Issues with append, merge and join for 3 different dataframe outputs from pandas with 1 index

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I have 10000 data that I'm sorting into a dictionary and then exporting that to a csv using pandas. I'm sorting temperatures, pressures and flow associated with a key. But when doing this I find: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pWWBb.jpg 
but I want something like this:https://i.stack.imgur.com/aYDmh.jpg

I'm transposing my dataframe so the index can be rows but in this case I want only 3 rows 1,2, & 3, and all the data populate those rows.

```
flow_dictionary = {'200:P1F1':[5.5, 5.5, 5.5]}
pres_dictionary = {'200:PT02':[200,200,200],
                   '200:PT03':[200,200,200],
                   '200:PT06':[66,66,66],
                   '200:PT07':[66,66,66]}
temp_dictionary = {'200:TE02':[27,27,27], 
                   '200:TE03':[79,79,79],
                   '200:TE06':[113,113,113],
                   '200:TE07':[32,32,32]}

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(temp_dictionary, orient='index').T

df2 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(pres_dictionary, orient='index').T

df3 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(flow_dictionary, orient='index').T

df = df.append(df2, ignore_index=False, sort=True)

df = df.append(df3, ignore_index=False, sort=True)

df.to_csv('processedSegmentedData.csv')
```

SOLUTION:

df1 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(temp_dictionary, orient='index').T

df2 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(pres_dictionary, orient='index').T

df3 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(flow_dictionary, orient='index').T

df4 = pd.concat([df1,df2,df3], axis=1)

df4.to_csv('processedSegmentedData.csv')

Comment: What is your question ?

Comment: Please look at [How to create good pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) and provide a [mcve] including sample data (as text, not as a picture) and sample output

Comment: Without _sample_ input and preferred output, it's hard to test any solutions against what you're trying to achieve given your inputs

Comment: @G.Anderson How's this?

Comment: I think I was writing df1 instead of df4 when I was using concat but this worked for me for future users: 
df1 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(temp_dictionary, orient='index').T
df2 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(pres_dictionary, orient='index').T
df3 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(flow_dictionary, orient='index').T

df4 = pd.concat([df1,df2,df3], axis=1)

df4.to_csv('processedSegmentedData.csv')